# События на кнопку назад, вперед

Tags: jquery, history-api, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть popUp окно и вот когда открывается изменятся урл с помощью

```
history.pushState(data,title, url);
```

когда нажимаю кнопку назад урл меняется т.е. становится как прежде, так вот хотелось бы еще и окошку закрыть, но как можно поймать событию на кнопку назад и вперед?

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
                var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        alert(hash);
```

этот не сработал. В гугле вообще не могу найти материалов:(

Comment: window.onpopstate 

[window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через такую функцию реализовать:

```
window.onpopstate = function( e ) {
//Ваши действия
}
```